# NS3 Bandwidth utilisation on network's links

Tags: ns-3

In NS3, I'm trying to set up a simulation in which I calculate the bandwidth usage of the various links in my network at regular intervals.

I've seen in the documentation that it's fairly easy to obtain statistics on the various flows passing through the network using the `FlowMonitor` and `FlowMonitorHelper` classes.
However, I can't find anything that allows me to obtain statistics directly on the network links, and the NS3 documentation isn't always very clear and complete.

In particular, I'd like to get the bandwidth utilization rate on each of the network links. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Thank you in advance :)